# display last 6 entries in a channel

Tags: conditionals

Have

- events channel
- have 10 entries (the channel can have varying range of entries for example it has 10)
- have a date field called event_start_date
- ex. current date is 2016-05-30

Desire
 - dynamically display last 6 entries in this sorted list
 - this list can have

List

- 2016-02-08
- 2016-03-01
- 2016-03-29
- 2016-05-02
- 2016-05-15
- 2016-05-30
- 2016-09-12
- 2016-10-24
- 2016-11-01
- 2016-12-06

Desired Results:

- 2016-05-15
- 2016-05-30
- 2016-09-12
- 2016-10-24
- 2016-11-01
- 2016-12-06

Unsure how to grab the last 6 entries always in a channel.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straight forward, just use the sort order (default is desc) and limit parameters.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my-channel" sort="asc" limit="6"}
    ...
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Using  `sort="asc"` will provide the dates in the reverse order to that required.  To get them in the right order will either require a tiny bit of inefficient processing - loop through the whole list and only display those that are within 6 of the total number of entries in list - or capturing the reverse list in a storage mechanism (e.g. Stash) and putting them out from there in reverse order.

Comment: i'm looking to get the last 6 entires of the list the in order list above form date 2016-05-30.  thanks but not exactly the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

ok had to use the query option but here's the code

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_13 > '1' ORDER BY field_id_13 asc LIMIT 6) AS tableStore) AS tableStore ORDER BY field_id_13 DESC"}
        {field_id_13 format='%Y-%m-%d'}<br>
{/exp:query}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the search parameter:

```
search:event_start_date=">=2016-05-30"
```

to the channel entries tag.